# Ordering with search in brackets ui laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, admin

I am using brackets ui in my laravel admin panel
I am trying to sort my list by desc order with search as well but it is not working

My Controller and I have tried that

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // create and AdminListing instance for a specific model and
        $data = AdminListing::create(Order::class)->attachOrdering('id', 'desc')->processRequestAndGet(
        // pass the request with params
            $request,
            // set columns to query
            ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'phone', 'total_amount', 'status','discount','user_order_note'],
            // set columns to searchIn
            ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'phone', 'total_amount', 'status','discount','user_order_note']
        );
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return ['data' => $data];
        }
        return view('admin.orders.index', ['data' => $data]);
    }
```

Have done this according to the [documentation](https://getcraftable.com/docs/3.0/listing#ordering).

It does not give an error, but does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add get()  method 
please modify the query like below.
$data = AdminListing::create(Order::class)->attachOrdering('id', 'desc')->processRequestAndGet(
        // pass the request with params
            $request,
            // set columns to query
            ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'phone', 'total_amount', 'status','discount','user_order_note'],
            // set columns to searchIn
            ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'phone', 'total_amount', 'status','discount','user_order_note']
        )->get();
```